# Build event with current date

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have found a question about how to add assembly version to the build event, so I want to know if I can get good formatted date, which I can use it in the build event? And can I customize its form? Just like: 2017-09-21 or 2017:09:21.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I can get good formatted date, which I can use it in the build event?

Yes, you can. In [MSBuild 4.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2010/04/02/msbuild-property-functions/), Microsoft addressed this by adding "property functions" which allow you to execute a variety of regular .NET API calls during evaluation or execution. So you can use below scripts to call current data directly:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
      <CurrentDate>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyyMMdd))</CurrentDate>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

To use this code snippet, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag, add above code snippet. Then you can use `$(CurrentDate)` to get the current data and use it in your project. Of course, including build event.

Besides, if you want change the format of the current data, you can change the format: `yyyyMMdd`, like `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy:MM:dd`.

For more Date/time tostring formats, you can refer to [DateTime.ToString() Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

Comment: Thanks, That works for me.